# How to make jenkins trigger a build on a dependent projects when a dependency is build

Tags: maven, build, jenkins, maven-3, pom.xml

I have what seems to be a simple question regarding how to setup Jenkins and maven 3.

For the sake of simplicity lets say that we have four projects:

**Model** which has no dependencies
**Commons** which depends on Model
**Server** which depends on Common and Model
**Frontend** which depends on Model

What I want to achieve is that a success build on Model triggers new build on all projects which in its pom has a dependency on Model (here Common, Server and Frontend)

If Common fails then there is no need to build Server.

In the above case it seems that I can fix this by manually setting up dependent projects on Model and Commons but this information can already be found in the pom files for each project (Server and Frontend) which makes me conclude/wish that Jenkins should be able to figure this out by it self.

Can Jenkins deduce the dependency tree by parsing the pom on each project defined in Jenkins and do some kind of optimal build order / dependency handling automatically or do I have to setup "Block build when upstream project is building" and "Build after other projects are built [List of dependent projects]" as described above ?

I am using Jenkins version 1.473 and Maven 3.
Our maven project pom's do not use the parent or module tag.

/Benjamin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution for such thing is to create a [multi-module build](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) which results in the following structure:

```
root (pom.xml)
  +--- model (pom.xml)
  +--- commons (pom.xml)
  +--- server (pom.xml)
  +--- frontend (pom.xml)
```

In each module for example in commons you define a dependency to the model module etc.
The build order will be automatically done by maven.

With such kind of project you can simply go to the root and do:

```
mvn clean package
```

You can also use:

```
mvn --pl --am server
```

which will build server but also all depending modules automatically.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that all modules gets build every time ?
I would like it to only build the necessary parts depending on which project was getting the build request.

Comment: In jenkins there is a configuration which is named "incremental build" this will build only what has changed.

Comment: Does this mean all of the projects need to be merged and/or exist in the same repo?  What if they are spread across different repos?

Comment: That this will not work...only for a multi module build which is within a single repo (But I'm not sure if this even exists in recent versions of Jenkins).  (Post is 7 Years old!)

Comment: This unfortunately has nothing to do with Jenkins.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to stick with 4 individual builds rather than a multi-module build, then the way to do it is in each of the 4 projects check the box under build triggers

"Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"

Then you do a checkin to Model, jenkins starts a build of that project based on SVN polling, when the build completes, it see that common has a dependency on model, and so it triggers a build of common to see if it still builds against the updated model.

The jenkins jobs must be created as maven jobs for this option to be present. It is not applicable to free-style projects, even if they run a script which happens to invoke maven.

Comment: I don't see such a build trigger. Does it require a plugin?

Comment: Make sure you have created a maven job and not a free-style job. It doesn't require an extra plugin, as the maven plugin is included in the base install

Comment: Thanks but I am in fact sing freestyle projects. You may want to add tat info to your answer though.

Comment: You don't know by chance how to enable this in jenkins pipelines? (via jenkinsfile)

Comment: Seems need to install `maven integration` plugin by hand first, the plugin is not installed by default in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions.

1. Create a Module pom above the other projects that only declare the build order (model, commons, server and frontend). And just install this project into Jenkins
2. In each job, there is check box to activate in the form "what is triggering the build" --> build after projects. (The name of the option are probably not exactly what I wrote since my Jenkins is configured in French...)

Comment: Will #1 cause that when building Common that Server and Frontend gets build as well since they depends on Common and Model doesn't gets build since it's build wasn't triggered (as there was no SCM change)</br>

#2 is what I tried to describe as what I am currently doing. This means that I have to manually set build dependencies for Model and all other non top level projects. What I would like is to find out if there is a way for Jenkins to figure this out by it self without me redefining what already can be found by looking in each pom for each project.